# Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [contentbackchainchannel] creator org

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I've fabric network setup with two orgs; orchestratororg and participantorg.

With user of orchestratororg I can invoke or query chaincode but when trying to query with user of participantorg I get an error as follows:

> "Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [contentbackchainchannel]
>   creator org [ParticipantOrgMSP]"

You can access my network setup under [Network config](https://github.com/onenetwork/onechain-back/tree/master/hyp/content-backchain)

Comment: Facing same issue, Let me know if found any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following commands,

Inside fabric-tools folder

```
./teardownFabric.sh
./startFabric.sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

Then go to business card and run following.

Make sure you already created archive file for your business card (tutorial-network):

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna

composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

Refer this link for more
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the value of CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID if exactly same as the value that you have set in the configtx.yaml.
or maybe already channel exists

Answer (score 0):

Check if the participantorg's peers joined to the channel or not.
The peer who is interacting with channel must joined the channel.
Channel also have one channel MSP in which it keep the information of joined peers.
So when you're trying to interact with channel with the peer which is yet not joined the channel will get the error message.